Allowing Public Access to an S3 Folder Using Policies
I made an S3 bucket to hold my digital products that i will be selling(digital art for now). I made 2 folders, one for watermarked images, another for unwatermarked images. I accomplished this before by enabling ACLs but i wanted to try to use policies to restrict access to some folders in the bucket, and grant public access to other folders in the bucket. this is my policy, but it doesnt seem to have worked for some reason. Am I missing something?
This is my policy:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::-----/-----/*"
    }
  ]
}

I kept ACLs disabled, allowed for public access, and created a policy specifically for the folder that i wanted to be accessed.



Your policy looks correct and you should not be using ACLs these days. How are you testing the policy? What happens when you attempt to access an object in that directory?

I try to access it from the internet using the object key url

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

Created a new Amazon S3 bucket bucket-name
Turned off S3 Block Public Access
Added a policy of:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/foo/*"
    }
  ]
}


Uploaded an image to the foo directory
Used this URL in my browser: https://my-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo/image.png (I'm in the Sydney region and I used the URL displayed in the S3 console)

The image was successfully displayed.
You might want to try this for yourself and then compare it to the configuration on your non-working bucket.

made a new bucket and it looks like that worked. Thank you! I will have to see why it wasnt working for my other one
